# Return value with a jQuery function

Tags: jquery, angularjs, return, http-get

How do I get a return value from the following function , so that I could use the returned value in my angular controller:

```
var demoService = angular.module('demoService', [])
    .service('myService', function($http, $q) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get('http://enlytica.com/RSLivee/rest/census').then(function(data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        });


        this.getdata = function() {
            var dataarr = [];
            var v = 0;

            var datarec = function datafetch() {
                $http.get('http://enlytica.com/RSLivee/rest/census').then(function(data) {
                    var v = data.data.Tweets[0].FAVOURITE_COUNT;
                    console.log(data.data.Tweets[0]);
                    return (({
                        maxValue: 4000,
                        animationSpeed: 100,
                        val: v
                    }));
                });
            }
            var datarec = datafetch();
            console.log(datarec);
            return datarec;
        }

    })
```

Comment: You can't, you need to use a promise....

Comment: I have tried that already  , have used promise inside "service.js" as well as my "controller.js" .Below is how i used it in Service.js
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30298386/passing-angular-service-data-to-gaugechart-controller

Answer (score 0):

I think this will works as expect:

```
 this.getdata = function() {
   return $http.get('http://enlytica.com/RSLivee/rest/census').then(function(data) {
     var v = data.data.Tweets[0].FAVOURITE_COUNT;
     return {
       maxValue: 4000,
       animationSpeed: 100,
       val: v
     };
   });
 }
```

To consume the service from the controller:

```
//The result of service.getdata() is just a promise, you can chain it howerver you like
service.getdata().then(function(data){
//The data here should be: {  maxValue: 4000, animationSpeed: 100, val: v}
 console.log(data); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response ,but It doesn't read data from the url when i use return with the $http/http and if i don't use the return ,i cant return the value to my controller.Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you use console.log to log the v? Does the program reach the log?

Comment: yes I used the console.log(v) , but it doesnt reach the log .it threw an error in the first place when i put [$http,$q] as a dependency injection , so i had to remove it .Here is the error it shows with the DI              
     `Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/ng/areq?p0=fn&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%string
    at Error (native) .....`
so i removed the  "[   ]" part and  I still get the data if i  remove the"return" keyword but then i can't return it to the controller.

Comment: Can you try the code in this fiddle, I think it may works: http://jsfiddle.net/3qrkww8g/

Comment: I tried it , it does show in the console when I run it from the fiddle .But the same wouldn't happen in my Project code. 

http://tinypic.com/r/2q1z6gj/8       Here is the structure of my code , I also added the module "demoService" in the dashboard.html where the controllers div is located .But it still doesn't work. Should i add the module name in the index file also ?
Thanks In Advance